# PhoneGap Business App

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, phonegap

I am trying to replicate the tutorial Learn PhoneGap Development/Making Business App in 30 Minutes.

At: [Learn PhoneGap Development | Making Business App in 30 Mins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je-VIKhUIgI)

I am using jquery-3.2.1.min.js, Bootstrap.min.js --version 3.3.7.
I am also using bootstrap.min.css version 3.3.7 from [https://bootswatch.com](https://bootswatch.com/)

I am using the Phone Gap Framework. I am also using the started code from [Bootstrap starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/starter-template/)

[Starter Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy4U6.png)

I am trying to replicate the  tutorial Learn PhoneGap Development/Making Business App in 30 Mins. I am not able to replicate the code.

[How my code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzrXf.png)

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6XG.png)

my HTML Code:

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
            <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap,min.css" />
            <title>Acme Mobile </title>
        </head>
```

Ending Code:

```
<div class="app">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the stylesheet(s) are not being applied. Looking at your code, there is a typo in the last `<link>` in the `<head>` section. It currently looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap,min.css" />
```

And it should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Notice the comma replaced by a period.

Hope that helps.